# Laravel 5 soft delete : SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry

Tags: php, laravel

i have a laravel 5 project and i want to use the soft delete methode, but after each delete i got this sql error message:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '7' for key 'PRIMARY' (SQL: insert into `fairkatert_task` (`id`, `user_id`, `editor_id`, `title`, `task`, `status`, `deadline_date`, `deleted_at`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `milestone_id`) values (7, 1, 1, asdasdasdasdasd, asdasdasdasdasdasdasda, open, 2016-12-28 00:00:00, 2015-10-02 07:16:26, 0000-00-00 00:00:00, 0000-00-00 00:00:00, 0))
```

i tried to turn off the timestamps but it doesn't stop, i google it and i can't find any solution for me.

migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('task', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('user_id')->references('id')->on('user')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('editor_id')->references('id')->on('user')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('task');
        $table->enum('status', array('open', 'close', 'reopen'))->default('open');
        $table->timestamp('deadline_date');
        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

model:

```
<?php

  namespace App\Http\Models;

   use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

  class Task extends Model
   {
      use SoftDeletes;

public    $timestamps = true;
protected $table      = 'task';
protected $fillable   = [ 'user_id', 'editor_id', 'title', 'task', 'status', 'deadline_date' ];
protected $dates      = [ 'deadline_date', 'deleted_at', 'created_at', 'updated_at' ];
```

thank you for help.

Comment: Your db have a row with id = 7 ??? You can check column deleted_at of this row.

Comment: You're re-inserting for some reason. You're not updating. That's the first clue that you must investigate. There's a mistake somewhere in your code and the code you posted isn't the most relevant piece of the code we need to crack where logic goes wrong with what you've written.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you two i have found my problem.

```
$task->delete();
$task->save();
```

I dont why, but i used the save method after deleting the record.
That it was so easy, problem solved.